# img's sizes attribute scales images up, doesn't obey max-width

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I'm trying to implement responsive images for content images (images within articles), the `img/srcset/sizes` way. I have a responsive site with a single column layout for mobile and tablet with images stretching to 100%. I use a `max-width: 100%; height: auto;` in CSS and would expect the images to not exceed their original dimensions.

However, in my images' sizes attribute I've defined a default size of `100vw` for mobile and tablet. This works for images whose largest version has a width larger than what turns out to be `100vw`. However this pumps up smaller images, whose original size is smaller than the `100vw`, so that they become really ugly.

I thought `max-width: 100%;` on images would prevent them from scaling up larger than they should be. And I understood the `sizes` attribute as a way of telling the browser in which size the image is going to be displayed, but did not expect it to scale the image - or at least obey to added CSS rules.

I have the same behavior in Chrome and Firefox... so I'm not sure if this is related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007916/chrome-does-not-display-suitable-srcset-picture)

BTW: The sizes attribute is set programmatically in an import script, so large and small images are treated the same way.

Any idea what I'm doing or understanding wrong. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You seem to have misunderstood the concept. Using `max-width:100%;` will only limit the width to 100% of the container. Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/pnz2kgxL/ (try recizing the panel).

Comment: max-width:100% is judged by the size of the parent element, not the original image dimensions ^^.

Comment: thanks for your fiddles! i think i misunderstood that since the more common case is fitting a large image in a small container.

do you have a suggestion for dealing with images smaller than their container? when i add the `sizes` attribute it seems to work like a `width` attribute and scales the image, so e.g. `100vw` will inflate it. probably i'd need to set the image versions' respective widths as the widths in `sizes`, huh?

something like: 

`srcset="large-600x400.jpg 600w, small-300x200.jpg 300w" sizes="(max-width: 400px) 300px, 600px"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood the concept.

`max-width` only limits the width based on the parent container.

You can easily see the effect here:

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x150.png" width="500" style="max-width:100%;">
    
<div style="max-width:50%;">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150.png" width="1000" style="max-width:100%;">
</div>
```

If you want to limit the image size, wrap it in a div.

Then, on that div, you set the width you wish.

The images will scale up to that width.

Basically, just like how I did with the `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a guess, but have you tried adding `width:auto;` before `max-width:100%`?